# Pushing Website Ecommerce Data into GA Mobile App Property

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

A New app im developing doesn't have a payment methods within the app but makes the sale on a website, I want to pass the Ecommerce Data from the website order confrimation into the mobile App profile on GA instead of tracking them in a website property. Is this possible?